# Returning Names from a Table dependant on a Cell Value and then Filtering

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

I have 3 different tables filled with names and job roles for people in 3 different companies. I need to return a table of names with a certain job title based on the value of a cell that says which company they belong to.

Can anyone help me out with a bit of excel magic?

Comment: The names have to return to a table so I can apply a data validation list to allow the selection of these names.

Comment: Have you tried anything

Comment: try with hlookup, vlookup or Index+match

Comment: The data has to be pulled into another table and has to be able to have the ability to change when the company name is changed.

Comment: @ReganK1998 yes that is possible, personally i would have used `POWER QUERY` which is very dynamic, with simple steps and its a one time operation, !

Answer (score 0):

I used a VBA function in order to get the results I required.

With an `IF` command to set the variable of the different companies, the contacts belonged to and then added the following code within the `IF` function:

```
Dim RngWS As Worksheet
    Dim CoverSheet As Worksheet
    Dim UKCompanyMembers As Range
    Dim DropdownRange1 As Range
    Dim DropdownRange2 As Range

    Set RngWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Team Members")
    Set CoverSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cover Sheet")

    Set UKCompanyMembers = RngWS.Range("UK_Company_Members[Names]")
    Set DropdownRange1 = CoverSheet.Range("B5")
    Set DropdownRange2 = CoverSheet.Range("B6")

    With DropdownRange1.Validation
    .Delete 'delete previous validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:="='" & RngWS.Name & "'!" & UKCompanyMembers.Address
    End With
```

I then applied the next `IF` function for US team members and included the same code as above but altered for the US Company Members, then again for the Asia company members.